# Can anyone tell me what type of worm this is?

Tags: species-identification

[image]
I sure hope you can see this picture. Need to know what type of worm this is. Found one in July and one just now inching its way across my tiled floor. I live in Florida. It is one color all the way around, dark red.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see the head clearly but based on

1: it is a big worm cruising around on land 
and
2: you have never seen one before

I bet on this

[image: flatworm]

From linked article.

> The flatworm (Platydemus manokwari) has few natural predators outside
>   of New Guinea, and it likely will have no predators in the United
>   States, Justine says. It gobbles up soil-dwelling invertebrates like
>   snails, which could have a big impact on the environment.

Comment: I checked wiki for this worm and it says it has a lighter colored underside. This worm is the same color all-around

Comment: Does your worm have a semicircular head?  Or a pointy head like an earthworm?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't know anything about worms but I think it has a pointy head?